# React Native: How to check if we are at end of the flatlist?

Tags: react-native

I want to hide a view when I am already at end of the list and show the view only when i am in mid of the flatlist .I would like to know how can we check the end of the list?

Comment: by end you mean if user scrolled to the bottom of the list to load more data or if there is no more data to be loaded? please provide some code of what are you trying to achieve so we can understand the problem

Comment: You can use event onScroll and extract index e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y.

Comment: I am showing Unread message Label , and I do not want to show it when we are already at end of list. Something similar to that of Whatsapp chat. I want a logic to hide that label.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onEndReached](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached) to check if user has reached end of FlatList.

```
<FlatList
   ...
   ...
   onEndReached={() => {
          this.setState({
             showText : true
         }}
/>
```

Now you can do

```
showText ? <Text>New Message</Text>: null
```

Comment: I do not want to check if user has reached end of flatlist. I want a condition where the user is already at end of list:

{(/*condition to check if user is end of flatlist*/) && <Text>New Message</Text>

Comment: @BhagyaShree I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<FlatList
  onScroll={event => {
    const isAtAnd =
      event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y + 
      event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height === event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height 
}}/>
```